# Docker compose - modificar puerto mysql

Tags: php, laravel, php7, docker, docker-compose

Mi stack es **windows** + **docker** y estoy configurando mi docker-composer y me gustaria dejar los puertos 80 para apache y el puerto 3306 para mysql ya que los tengo como servicios, me gustaria poner por ejemplo el mysql en el puerto **3307**

Actualmente tengo este fichero docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'
services: 
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: 'laravelapp'
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'laraapp_db'
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
```

Donde pone **ports** no se si debo poner "3306:3307" o como debo hacerlo.
Una vez hecho esto debo reiniciar el docker?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Deberías Poner:

```
"3307:3306"
```

[Referencia Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50457267/4717133)

### También es importante que el MySql este Configurado el puerto 3307:

1. Abra el archivo "my.ini" en el directorio de instalación del
2. servidor MySQL Verá el número de puerto predeterminado "port=3306"
3. Cámbielo al número de puerto deseado.
4. Después de cambiar, guarde el archivo "my.ini"
5. Reinicie el servidor MySQL

[Referencia MySql](https://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysql-default-port-number-and-how-to-change-it.shtml)

### Instancia y exponer:

Comando para iniciar el contenedor MySQL en el puerto 3306 y exponer en el puerto 3307

```
docker container run -d --name=LocalMySQLDB -p 3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql
```

o:

```
docker run -d --name=LocalMySQLDB -p 3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql
```

El comando anterior inicia el servidor de base de datos MySQL dentro del contenedor "LocalMySQLDB"

Ahora, para conectarse a la instancia de mysql en contenedor, use el siguiente comando adjunto

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -P 3307 -ppassword
```

He intentado esto muchas veces en mi máquina local con fines de prueba. Definitivamente también funcionará para ti. Por favor comente si no funcionará en su caso.

**Debes adecuarlo a tu necesidad, y si el primer punto de los puertos se mantiene**

Comment: Mi pregunta es, puedo tener la instancia de mysql en el puerto 3306 y luego un docker con la imagen de mysql que corra en otro puerto? Esa es mi pregunta gracias

Comment: Perfecto 1000 gracias